# Where is wrong in this code to plot intersection of a plane and a sphere?

Tags: graphics3d

I am trying to plot the circle is intersection of the sphere with center `O(0,0,0)` and radius `R` and the plane `z = h`. I tried

```
R = 4;
h = R - 5;
p = {0, 0, h};
v = {0, 0, 1};
sph = Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, R];
hp = Hyperplane[p, v];
reg = RegionIntersection[sph, hp];
Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.5], sph}, {Opacity[.5], hp}, {Opacity[.5], 
   reg}}, Boxed -> False]
```

I cannot get the result. How can I get correct result?

Comment: `DiscretizeRegion@reg`

Comment: Never use upper-case letters for your variables (e.g., $R$), as they can conflict with internal naming conventions.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thank you very much.

Comment: `Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.5], sph}, {Opacity[.5], hp}, {Opacity[.5], 
   HighlightMesh[
    DiscretizeRegion[reg], {Style[1, Thickness[.01], Red], 
     Style[0, None]}]}}, Boxed -> False]`